On some interesting property of subsets which are non-invariant under regular group action
Let $G$ be a regular group acting on set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Suppose that $\Gamma_0\cup\ldots\cup\Gamma_{r-1} = \{1,\ldots,n\}$ is the partition of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Let $\Gamma_t$ be a subset which is not invariant under $G$ action, i.e. $\forall g\in G$ $g(\Gamma_t) \not= \Gamma_t$. I'm considering two sums $S_1(g)$ and $S_2(g)$:
$$
S_1(g) = |\Gamma_t \setminus g(\Gamma_t)| + |g(\Gamma_t) \setminus \Gamma_t|, 
$$
$$
S_2(g) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{r-1}|\Gamma_i \cap g(\Gamma_t)|.
$$
If $G$ is regular then there is $g \in G$ such that $|\Gamma_t \setminus g(\Gamma_t)| \not= 0$.
$\textbf{Question}:$ When does exist any $g \in G$ such that the inequality $S_1(g) \leq S_2(g)$ holds?
$\textbf{My attempt.}$ I checked some regular groups as $C_6$, $Q_8$, $C_8$, $C_2\times C_2 \times C_2$ and for them the condition stay true. So I tried to proof that.
It can be proof that
$$
\max\limits_{g\in G} S_2(g) \geq \frac{\sum\limits^{r-1}_{i=0}|\Gamma_i|^2 - n}{n-1}
$$
and
$$
\min_{g} S_1(g) \leq \frac{1}{r}\left(n - \frac{\sum\limits^{r-1}_{i=0}|\Gamma_i|^2 - n}{n-1}\right)
$$
Then I tried to check that lower bound of $\max\limits_{g\in G} S_2(g)$ is greater than upper bound of $\min_{g} S_1(g)$. But it is not true. So here I stacked...
